# Copy uppercase name file bug

Tags: debian, ubuntu, rsync, cp

Enviroment: Debian 11 and 10
I try to copy the whole folder "/lib/modules/5.12.10" in Debian to USB.

But I found there are 8 files will confuse system which are:

1. xt_dscp.ko xt_DSCP.ko
2. xt_hl.ko xt_HL.ko
3. xt_rateest.ko xt_RATEEST.ko
4. xt_tcpmss.ko xt_TCPMSS.ko

No matter which file you copy first to USB, the system will consider that the second file has already existed.

I have already try these method:

1. Debian to USB: cp -r folderA folderB
2. Debian to USB: rsync -av --no-g --no-o folderA folderB
3. zip the folderA on Debian and unzip it to USB.
4. With Ubuntu live, copy folderA on Debian's partirion to USB: cp -r folderA folderB

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m guessing your USB-connected storage uses a case-insensitive file system such as FAT32. On such file systems, there is no way to store files with case-conflicting names except by resorting to some type of translation.

A better approach in your case is to archive all the files in a tarball or other archive, for example

```
tar cpJf /path/to/usb/modules-5.12.10.tar.xz /lib/modules-5.12.10
```

You won’t be able to see the individual files on the USB device itself, but you will be able to extract them whenever necessary.

Comment: I use ext4 USB and it works fine. Thank you!!